# Positioning a bottom element at vertical center

Tags: android, layout, position, center

I was trying to search everywhere but nothing.

There is no problem in RelativeLayout to position anything to center by

`android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"`

but i want to position my buttonimage bottom to center so it lies above the central line..

[image]

how could this be done to any size of screen and button, or i have to know buttons size?

Comment: can u try `android:layout_centerInParent=true`

Comment: share xml code what you done

Comment: it's all nice but nobody understand... i don't want that picture on center but above center.. like imageY = displayheight/2+imageHeight/2 i don't know how to explain it more..

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```